# Pandas: How can I find col, index where Nan value exists?

Tags: python, pandas

```
In [3]: import numpy as np

In [4]: b = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
   ...:     [1,np.nan,3,4],
   ...:     [np.nan, 4, np.nan, 4]
   ...: ]))

In [13]: b
Out[13]:
     0    1    2    3
0  1.0  NaN  3.0  4.0
1  NaN  4.0  NaN  4.0
```

I want to find column name and index where `Nan` value exists.

For example, "`b` has `NaN` value at `index 0, col1`, `index 0, col0`, `index 1 col2`.

What I've tried:

1

```
In [14]: b[b.isnull()]
Out[14]:
    0   1   2   3
0 NaN NaN NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

=> I don't know why it shows `DataFrame` filled with `NaN`

2

```
In [15]: b[b[0].isnull()]
Out[15]:
    0    1   2    3
1 NaN  4.0 NaN  4.0
```

=> It only shows part of `DataFrame` where `Nan` value exist in `column 0`..

How can I

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to find the indices where `pd.isnull(b)` is True:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

b = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    [1,np.nan,3,4],
    [np.nan, 4, np.nan, 4]]))

idx, idy = np.where(pd.isnull(b))
result = np.column_stack([b.index[idx], b.columns[idy]])
print(result)
# [[0 1]
#  [1 0]
#  [1 2]]
```

or use [`DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to reshape the DataFrame by moving the column labels into the index.
This creates a Series which is True where `b` is null:

```
mask = pd.isnull(b).stack()
# 0  0    False
#    1     True
#    2    False
#    3    False
# 1  0     True
#    1    False
#    2     True
#    3    False
```

and then read off the row and column labels from the MultiIndex:

```
print(mask.loc[mask])
# 0  1    True
# 1  0    True
#    2    True
# dtype: bool

print(mask.loc[mask].index.tolist())
# [(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2)]
```